# How to make gamepad keys fire slower?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, controller

I'm currently making a game with html5, css and javascript, it works as it should and all, but when I press a button on my wired xbox360 controller, it fires the callback I've set almost 50 times in less than a second!

How do I make the callback only fire once per second using the Gamepad API in JavaScript?

I've tried using a cooldown timer like so

```
var pressCool = false;

if(buttonPressed(xbox.stick2)){
    if(!pressCool){
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.keyCode = keys.custom.stick2;
        $(document).trigger(e);
        pressCool = true;
    }
}

setTimeout(function(){
    if(pressCool){
        pressCool = false;
    }
}, 1000);
```

But this still gives me more than one firing of the callback.

Comment: @hindmost Why would you need my code? I'm not asking for help on my code, nor asking for code, rather on how I would do something.

Comment: Without code your question is off-topic as too broad

Comment: How is my question too broad when I'm asking **one** thing? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You made zero efforts to solve your problem and now expect someone solve it for you. This is a reason to close your question. However I haven't voted to close it yet, nor downvoted it. Instead of this, I suggest you to show evidence of your efforts.

Comment: Alright, I'll add some evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setTimeout` callback actually do nothing. On each call it only checks if `pressCool` flag is set, but it always equal to `false`, so this condition is never true.

The code outside `setTimeout` runs only once. Whereas it seems that it has to be called on each game frame (game loop iteration).

You have to place all code which relevant to game loop iteration into one function and place its call into `setTimeout` callback.

So your code should look like this:

```
...
function update() {
    if(pressCool){
        pressCool = false;
    }
    if(buttonPressed(xbox.stick2)){
        if(!pressCool){
            var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
            e.keyCode = keys.custom.stick2;
            $(document).trigger(e);
            pressCool = true;
        }
    }
    ...
}

setTimeout(function(){
    update();
}, 1000);
```

Also I recommend you to read the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Controls_Gamepad_API) relevant to your problem.

Comment: @Mackan90096 You could also upvote this answer if it solve your problem